# How to create time dimensional raster in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine

Is there a way to create multidimensional raster with bands differing in time (like [ArcGIS Multidimensional Rasters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/an-overview-of-multidimensional-raster-data.htm) or NetCDF files) in Google Earth Engine.

At the moment I can create multiband raster with bands named according to their timestamp. But this is not a proper multidimensional raster

```
var mCDI = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
          var defNDVI = modisDefi.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).mean().multiply(0.4)
          var defPrecip = precDefi.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).mean().multiply(0.4)
          var defSoil = soilDefi.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).mean().multiply(0.2)
          var mCDI = defNDVI.add(defPrecip).add(defSoil)
                        .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1).millis()).set('month', m).set('year',y)
        return mCDI
  });
}).flatten());

var mCDIbandName= years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) { return ee.String(ee.Number(y).toInt())
    .cat(ee.String('-'))
    .cat(ee.Number(m).format('%02d')); })
    }).flatten();
print(mCDIbandName, 'mCDIbandName')

var img_mCDI = mCDI.toBands().rename(mCDIbandName)
```

Which results into image with this structure:

```
Image (252 bands)
 type: Image
  bands: List (252 elements)
    0: "2001-01", double, EPSG:4326
     id: 2001-01
     crs: EPSG:4326
     crs_transform: [1,0,0,0,1,0]
     data_type: double
    1: "2001-02", double, EPSG:4326
    2: "2001-03", double, EPSG:4326
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You (probably) want an array-based image.  There's a number of ways to make those, but the most common is collection.toArray().  You'll want one of the bands of the input images to contain a date so there's a record of what date each value comes from.